# How can I change a sprite color when user touch it

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, 2d-games

I'm new to iOS development and SpriteKit.
I'm making a game and I need to change a sprite color when user touch it.
Actually, I have three determined color.
The sprite starts as red. When user touch it it turns blue. If user touches again it turns black. And if user touch it one more time it came red again.

In the touchbegan method I'm trying something like:

```
if (playerBar.color == [SKColor redColor]) {
    playerBar.color = [SKColor blueColor];
} else if (playerBar.color == [SKColor blueColor] {
    playerBar.color = [SKColor blackColor];
} else if (playerBar.color == [SKColor blackColor]) {
    playerBar.color = [SKColor redColor];
}
```

Anyone can help me?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

!!!Sorry for such a long answer, at the bottom you can find full solution both in Swift and Objective-C

You can change the color of a SKSpriteNode with animation which will look better using this approach:

Objective-C:

```
   SKAction *changeColorAction = [SKAction colorizeWithColor:[SKColor blueColor] colorBlendFactor:1.0 duration:0.5];
   [myLabel runAction:changeColorAction];
```

Swift:

```
   let changeColorAction = SKAction.colorizeWithColor(SKColor.blueColor(), colorBlendFactor: 1.0, duration: 0.5)
   playerBar.runAction(changeColorAction)
```

Here is a full solution in Swift for your problem, with touch checking, color comparison and changing. Actually your method of checking if current color of node is equal to a SKColor is not ok. So bellow I show you my solution for this, which may not be great, but works.

First of all, where you initialize your playerBar Sprite node, give it a name like:

```
  playerBar.name = "playerBar"
```

After, use the code bellow for SKColor comparison (not very accurate, but for this case works) and also for touches checking in node and color changing.

```
  func isEqualColor(color: SKColor, toColor: SKColor) -> Bool {
    let color1Components = CGColorGetComponents(color.CGColor)
    let color2Components = CGColorGetComponents(toColor.CGColor)

    if ((color1Components[0] != color2Components[0]) || //red
       (color1Components[1] != color2Components[1]) || //green
       (color1Components[2] != color2Components[2]) || //blue
       (color1Components[3] != color2Components[3])) { //alpha
        return false
    }

    return true
  }

  override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        /* Called when a touch begins */

      for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

        let nodes = self.nodesAtPoint(location) as [SKNode]

        for node in nodes {
          if node.name == "playerBar" {
            let spriteNode = node as SKSpriteNode
            var color = SKColor.redColor()

            if isEqualColor(spriteNode.color, toColor: SKColor.redColor()) {
              color = SKColor.blueColor()
            } else if isEqualColor(spriteNode.color, toColor: SKColor.blueColor()) {
              color = SKColor.blackColor()
            }

            let changeColorAction = SKAction.colorizeWithColor(color, colorBlendFactor: 1.0, duration: 0.5)
            spriteNode.runAction(changeColorAction) {
              spriteNode.color = color //On completion of action, we set color so after in comparison method not have conflicts while comparing color components
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

I couldn't leave you without a Obejctive-C solution for this :)
So again you need to give a name for you playerBar SpriteNode at its initialization.

```
playerBar.name = "playerBar";
```

And after use this methods for your complete solution:

```
- (BOOL)isEqualColor:(SKColor *)color1 toColor:(SKColor *)color2
{
  const CGFloat* color1Components = CGColorGetComponents([color1 CGColor]);
  const CGFloat* color2Components = CGColorGetComponents([color2 CGColor]);

  if ((color1Components[0] != color2Components[0]) || //red
      (color1Components[1] != color2Components[1]) || //green
      (color1Components[2] != color2Components[2]) || //blue
      (color1Components[3] != color2Components[3])) { //alpha
    return NO;
  }

  return YES;
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
      CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];

      NSArray *nodes = [self nodesAtPoint:location];

      for (SKNode *node in nodes) {
        if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"playerBar"]) {
          SKSpriteNode *spriteNode = (SKSpriteNode *)node;
          SKColor *color = [SKColor redColor];

          if ([self isEqualColor:spriteNode.color toColor:[SKColor redColor]]) {
            color = [SKColor blueColor];
          } else if ([self isEqualColor:spriteNode.color toColor:[SKColor blueColor]]) {
            color = [SKColor blackColor];
          }

          SKAction *changeColor = [SKAction colorizeWithColor:color colorBlendFactor:1.0 duration:0.5];
          [spriteNode runAction:changeColor completion:^{
            spriteNode.color = color; //On completion of action, we set color so after in comparison method not have conflicts while comparing color components
          }];
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming you're registering touches correctly,  you have to assign playerBar a colorBlendFactor

```
playerBar.colorBlendFactor = 1.0;
```

the colorBlendFactor is a floating-point value that describes how the color is blended with the sprite’s texture.

Answer (score -2):

```
-(void)changeColor
{
    int color = 1;

    if (color == 1 || color > 3) {
        playerBar.color = [SKColor redColor];
        color = 1;
    }if else(color == 2) {
        playerBar.color = [SKColor blueColor];
    }if else(color == 3) {
        playerBar.color = [SKColor blackColor];
    }

    color++;
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInNode:self.scene];
    SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:touchLocation];
    if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"yourSpriteName"]) {
        [self changeColor];
    }
}
```